# I am sending the data via Swagger API but not able to receive data in Node

Tags: node.js, swagger-ui

I am trying to send data to a node API via swagger but I am not able to receive data in the backend. `req.body` is empty. any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

MY Swagger code:

```
/login:
    post:
      tags:
      - "login"
      summary: "User login"
      description: ""
      operationId: "auth"
      consumes:
      - "application/json"
      - "application/xml"
      - "html/text"
      produces:
      - "application/xml"
      - "application/json"
      - "html/text"
      parameters:
      - in: "body"
        name: "body"
        description: "User data that need to be passed for login "
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: "#/definitions/Login"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "Success input"
definitions:
  Login:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      username:
        type: "string"
    xml:
      name: "Login"        name: "Login"
```

---

backend code :

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);
})
```

Comment: backend code and swagger is running on different ports and servers

Comment: Check the browser console - are there any errors when you send the request?

Comment: @Helen , No I am not getting any error in the browser console

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express middleware, you need to add body-parser to be able to access req.body:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Import it:

```
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
```

And add:

```
let server = new Express();
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({// to support URL-encoded bodies
extended: true
}));
```

Comment: it is working when I am sending data via ajax or making use of postman but not working if sending via swagger

Comment: You didnt mention that its working on postman or ajax in your questin...